# Lime tree is dying

Tags: diagnosis, citrus

My lime tree has been doing well for several years but in the last few days the leaves have curled up. [image: leaves]

It's getting enough water and I put some citrus food on the base. I also noticed these markings on the trunk.[image: trunk]

Any ideas what the problem might be?

We're in New Zealand so it's autumn here.

Comment: If this was my tree, I would call an arborist as soon as possible.  I delayed with a crab-apple tree, and now it is dead.